# how to disable portrait mode for the components when device rotates in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode7

I have a background Image, to a view of size full screen.

This code creates the view:

```
UIImageView *backgroundView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
backgroundView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"fullscreen.jpg"];
```

When I rotate my phone to landscape its dimensions change. So how can I disable landscape rotation of my view so that for any rotation its frame will not change.

The view in question:

[image]

Comment: You want the rotation to be stopped for this instance or for whole app. For whole app under General unselect landscape

Answer (score 0):

Lets to see general property of project -> Deployment Info (checkbox "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right"). I hope this will help.

Programmatically:
You can override method "supportedInterfaceOrientations" 
something like this:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

Comment: thanks that works. Can you suggest me a pro-grammatical way.